# SDL2 configuration on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks, pkg-config, sdl-2, sdl-image

i've installed SDL2 (with SDL2_image and SDL2_ttf as well) from sources - SDL2 from http://www.libsdl.org/hg.php , SDL2_image and SDL2_ttf did I find on http://archive.ubuntu.com/ . The project I'm working with (using CodeBlocks) builds successfully, but when i run it, I get error messages in XTerm:

```
Failed loading png_set_longjmp_fn: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: undefined symbol:    _png_set_longjmp_fn
```

Then I try to reinstall SDL2_image, but rebuilding it not with `$ ./configure` but with

```
$ ./configure --disable-jpg-shared --disable-png-shared --disable-tif-shared --disable-webp-shared
```

But when I tried to make it then, it asked me to install automake, autoconf and m4, so I installed them. After some problems, I have another problems with configuring SDL2_image:

```
$ ./configure [--disable-jpg-shared --disable-png-shared --disable-tif-shared --disable-webp-shared]
(...)
./configure: line 12618: syntax error near unexpected token `SDL,'
./configure: line 12618: `    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SDL, sdl2 >= $min_sdl_version,'
```

What shall I do now?

And it may be useful that I (after `./configure` and `make`) use `checkinstall` when installing something.

Comment: Are you trying to build this for 32 r 64 bits

Comment: Try *apt-get install libpng12-dev* to solve your first problem.

Comment: I have libpng12-dev already installed. My Ubuntu 13.10 is 64 bit.

Comment: I've finally solved the problem and set up SDL2 on Ubuntu 13.10, but `SDL_PollEvent()` seems to clear whole contents of the window. What's the matter?

Comment: Start that as a new thread.

Comment: the last problem (syntax error in configure) is due to missing `pkg-config` in your toolchain.

Comment: also, note that after installing `pkg-config`, you'll probably need to do `autoreconf -i` or something similar, to recompile the `pkg.m4` into the `configure` script.